# How to show featured image block in custom post type for Author?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, author

I made a custom post type "Dream". Here is the code:

```
//Add custom post type by Akash
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type');
function create_post_type() {   
    register_post_type( 
        'dream',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Dreams' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Dream' ) 
            ),        
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'capability_type' => 'post',     
            'map_meta_cap' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Dreams'),
            'query_var' => false,    
            'delete_with_user' => true,
            'supports' => array( 
                'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 
                'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 
                'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' 
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
```

When I try to add the CPT "Dream" as Admin, it shows the featured image block to add media, but when I try to do same thing as Author, the featured image block is not shown. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and tested the CPT with an author account.The option to add a featured image showing up just fine.

[image: dashboard]

So just a heads up that the issue is not related to that specific CPT snippet, you should look elsewhere. Maybe a `functions.php` cleanup, disable plugins and/or try another theme using the snippet as a plugin to narrow down the search.